# Laravel Task Scheduler Crontab

Tags: laravel, cron, laravel-5.4

I can't get my cron working on my local server using Valet. Here's what I've got/done.

1. When I run `php artisan command:mycommand` the command runs.
2. When I run `php artisan schedule:run` the command runs.

> Output:

```
Running scheduled command: '/usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.13_6/bin/php' 'artisan' game:resources > '/dev/null' 2>&1 &
```

According to the Laravel docs it says to add this to my crontab.

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

When in my project directory, here is the pwd.

`/Users/tjhillard/Projects/galaxywars`

When I try `crontab -e` in my laravel project root and save this:

```
* * * * * php /Users/myusername/Projects/projectname schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

... it doesn't work. I've tried several variations of this cron command with no luck. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I'm on macOS using Valet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to add `artisan` add the end of the path. Try

```
* * * * * php /Users/myusername/Projects/projectname/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Haha I actually figured that out 30 seconds before you posted this. :P You get the checkmark though. Thank you very much anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Under 10.13 (High Sierra) the only command that worked is:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /Users/USER_NAME/PROJECTS_PATH/PROJECT/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```